# Locating a Encyclopedia Halachis Refuis

Tags: sources-mekorot, contemporary-halacha, gender-identity

I am looking for the following sefer: Encyclopedia Halachis Refuis (Entry: Erech Nituach Hafichas Min).

The entry speaks about what the authorities say on surgery and hormone treatments in regard to transgenderism.

Does anyone know where to find this sefer/entry? I tried to look online, using different translations, but could not find anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name in Hebrew is אנציקלופדיה הלכתית רפואית, and the word 'erech' (ערך) means entry, so it's not part of the entry's name. The encyclopedia is available online [here](https://www.medethics.org.il/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/). The entry you're looking for is in vol. 5, column 684 and onwards (see [here](https://www.medethics.org.il/article/%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D/)).